# How can I check which nodes have the highest value in a certain field?

Tags: rules, 7

My content type 'Article' has an integer field called 'Ranking'. How can I check which nodes have the three highest values after saving a new node or comment? I'd like to use the result in a rule, so I'm looking for some kind of "The node has ranking 1/2/3" condition.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: I'm thinking maybe try to filter the results via view and then use rules integration with views to get what you want, but it was the first thing coming into mind, maybe it's not that simple anyway

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/1113158

Comment: you can get idea here http://miss-hana.com/calculate-field-values-using-computed-field-in-drupal-7/ check this module too https://drupal.org/project/computed_field_tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If within your Computed Field you've selected `Store value in the database`, you can easily use Views to sort results based upon this field.

So, for example, in broad strokes, you could create a View that filtered on whatever you needed, most probably published and node type; then for sort, you would select this field and select descending; in paging, you'd select a specific number, eg, 3; and in fields, you'd select whatever you wanted to display.

If you wanted to have a block of the top three nodes, in the fields I could see you selecting the title and so forth, but if you are wanting to see if a specific node was in the top three, I'd just put the node nid in there.

So, if that's the case, when this View is run, it will return three nids.

If you look into [views_get_view_result()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7) you can quite easily access that output, eg:

```
$result=views_get_view_result('top_three'); // or whatever the name of the view is
```

will populate `$result` with something along these lines:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 2340
            [node_created] => 1390349535
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 1176
            [node_created] => 1390086303
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 1133
            [node_created] => 1390086313
        )

)
```

So, now you just have to look in there to see if your current nid is in there and if so, act accordingly.

Now, of course, the other question is where to put all of this?  I'd suggest looking into [hook_node_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) but be aware of the performance considerations of doing all of this each time a node is updated.  Caching is certainly your friend here.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds very promising! I created the top_three view you suggested: it displays the nids of the 3 articles with the highest value in the integer field 'Ranking'. Now, I'd like to create a new rule with an event like 'After saving new content' or 'A node has been flagged' that switches a 'Trophy' image field of the highest rated node (situated at the top in top_three) to some picture. I was wondering how I can get the condition right. Should I add an 'Execute custom PHP code' condition? What should the code look like? I'd create 2 similar rules for the 2nd & 3rd best rated content.

Comment: you could do this with custom php, eg, upon saving content, do whatever to get the node nid of the node that needs the gold badge, then load that node and set whatever you need in that node object and then save it; and etc on the silver and bronze.